# Downloading files - 403 Error

Tags: compiler-errors, maven-3, http-status-code-403, download

First of all I was trying to compile the jar for Spigot (Minecraft server .jar). However this error is given: http://i.gyazo.com/83e9b77bcf1d0d6ad79eaee98c73c2ff.png

Also i tried to start the Multicraft Panel, which also needs to download files from the internet. A 403 error was also given here: http://i.gyazo.com/546d3ffb1611e7e700532238d6b140e8.png

I have a feeling it may be the firewall blocking it, if so - what do I need to do to make it work. I have no antivirus software installed using OS: Windows 2012 Server R2

Thanks!

Comment: That's not how that works. A 403 means the web server (or a proxy server or other inline device) is responding to your machine. If a firewall were getting in the way, the connection would just time out or be refused.

Do you have any kind of proxy in place? (transparent or otherwise)

Comment: Nope, there is no proxy installed.